# What algorithm should I use for sampling from a black box probability function?

Tags: statistics, probability, mathematical-optimization, montecarlo, particle-filter

I have a function 'P(x)' where we query for any 'x' it gives a probability value. This function 'P' does not have a closed form and the evaluation is costly. Now 'x' is a set of vectors(matrix whose rows) which sum to 1 and each entry in the matrix is greater that 0.Now this distribution has many peaks and ridges. What method would be appropriate to sample from this 'P'. I want to approximate the distribution by a set of samples. So what would be the appropriate  method to use? Which method in MCMC or any would be suitable?

Comment: I have limited experience with it, but you could look into [Gibb's Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling).

Comment: Could you state this a bit more precisely? It sounds like your function can take as input any matrix with row sums of 1 and all positive entries. There are an infinite number of such matrices, so when you say `P(x)` is the probability of `x`, do you mean the pdf? Anyhow, you may have more luck asking at crossvalidated.com.

Comment: @josiliber The 'x' is a matrix is indeed in a continuous space that's why this is a hard problem. When I say P(x) yes I mean exactly the pdf value.